# Function Template Specialization for a specific templated type

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to specialize a template function for all the templated values of a specific type. I have the following function:

```
template <class T>
std::string toString(const T& t);
```

the following will allow me to specialize the function for a Vector2 of floats:

```
template <>
std::string toString<Vector2<float>>(const Vector2<float>& v);
```

but I would like a function to be specialized for all types of Vector2. I have tried something like this:

```
template <class T>
std::string toString(const Vector2<T>& v);
```

but when calling the toString() function like so:

```
Vector2<float> vec;
toString(vec);
```

the first function is called. How can I achieve this?

---

EDIT:

I may have left out an important detail, I was actually calling the function like so:

```
toString<Vector2<float>>(vec)
```

I didn't think that it made a difference but apparently it does, because when I call it without the

```
<Vector2<float>>
```

it worked fine. Why would this cause the undesired function to be called? Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the help.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7368da00a62395b2). Note: you're overloading `toString`, not specializing it -- and that is the right way. This ought to work.

Comment: @Quentin I suspect he wants to partially specialize a function. As you know it's not possible and thus the unexpected behavior because of the actual overloading. Need clarification.

Comment: found the issue, updates the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your case, it's possible to use alternative technique called overloading.

```
template <typename T>
std::string toString(const Vector2<T>& vec)
{
    //function body
}
```

Proof that proper function is being called: http://ideone.com/pR2Dyn

Comment: @Quentin he mentioned that wrong function is being called, but it's not possible ;) http://ideone.com/pR2Dyn

Comment: [Indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358958/function-template-specialization-for-a-specific-templated-type/41359040?noredirect=1#comment69919451_41358958). But until the question is clarified, repeating part of the "problematic" code won't help at all.